# Java 8 Update 60 Reduced Available Heap memory

Tags: java, windows, memory, netbeans-7

I am using Windows 7, on a PC with 32 GB of RAM, and have just accepted the latest Java 8 update (60).  Prior to the update, I used to be able to process files, in the command window, that required the use of several GB of memory.  Now, I get

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

running applications that require much less memory than I comfortably used before.

When I ran NetBeans, I used to be able to set the projects to use 1GB of memory by doing
R-click:Properties:Run and putting

```
-Xms1g
```

in the

```
VM Options
```

window.

Now, when I do that and try to run the program I get

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I don't get that error when I use

```
-Xms900m
```

instead.  So, Java has somehow reduced the amount of heap memory I can use.

I went to Start:Control Panel:Java (32-bit):Java:View

and put

```
-Xms4g
```

under

```
Runtime Parameters
```

but I still get the same errors.

Comment: Why do you use `-Xms`? This only sets the *minimum* heap, not the *maximum*. If you need to give your Java program more heap, you should use `-Xmx4g`

Comment: I went to Start:Control Panel:Java (32-bit):Java:View and put -Xmx4g under "Runtime Parameters".  I still get the same error message with Netbeans if I use -Xmx1g or -Xms1g under "VM Options".  Thanks,

Comment: If you use 32-bit, you are limiting yourself to around 1.3 GB of virtual memory.  This is a limitation of Windows XP you are emulating.

Comment: I have just replaced the 32-bit java with 64-bit.  I still have the same problem on Netbeans but the problem in the command window is at least not as bad.  I can run the program that was running out of heap memory before.  I am trying to run the program with more memory requirements.  I need to wait about half an hour to see if it works (unless it runs out of memory before then).  Thanks,

Comment: The settings in the control panel only affect Java Applets if I'm not mistaken, not Java programs started from the command line. To change the memory for a NetBeans project, you need to change the settings in **NetBeans**: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/run_debug_japps.htm#BABJHHGC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Windows, the 32-bit JVM has a maximum heap size of around 2GB and there is a way to bump that up to 3GB. If you're already running with 32GB RAM, then your Windows 7 must be 64-bit, and you would be better off just upgrading to a 64-bit JVM.

I've seen the available memory change from one Java release to the next.  They also fiddle with the default JVM memory sizes from one release to the next.  Finally, the amount of available heap varies with the number of threads running inside the JVM.  Since the max memory available for ALL purposes in 2GB, then more threads running decreases the amount left for heap.  If they added some threads in the Java 8 JVM, then that might explain why there's less heap available.

Comment: What you say certainly makes sense.   replaced 32-bit Java with 64-bit and that has certainly improved the situation in the command line.  The program, and parameters, that were giving the OutOfMemoryError error before is not running to completion.  I am currently testing with more memory intensive parameters that worked before the update.  I still have the problem with NetBeans.  I went to Start:Control Panel:Java (32-bit):Java:View and put -Xmx4g under "Runtime Parameters".   Would I be better off leaving that field blank?  Thanks,

Comment: The problem appears to be solved.  Upgrading from version 7 (32-bit) to version 8 fixed the NetBeans problem.  Thanks very much for your help,